# Is overriding commitProperties neccessary when updating Spark components?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex-spark

I understand that when creating a custom component, it's normally best practice to defer any property changes to it by using setters/getters, setting a "dirty" flag, calling invalidateProperties(), and then letting commitProperties() handle the actual changes.

But in the case where properties only affect Spark components, wouldn't this be redundant since Spark components already defer their property changes?

For instance, say I have a custom UIComponent that contains a Spark Button and I want to expose a buttonLabel property for it that changes the label of the button:

```
private var _buttonLabel:String;
private var myBtn:Button;
private var _buttonLabelChanged:Boolean = false;
function set buttonLabel(lbl:String){
   _buttonLabel = lbl;
   _buttonLabelChanged = true;
   invalidateProperties();
}
```

So then setting the buttonLabel property will then eventually trigger:

```
override protected function commitProperties(){
    if(_buttonLabelChanged){
          myBtn.label = _buttonLabel;
         _buttonLabelChanged = false;
    }
}
```

But the setter for "label" in the Spark Button class is already using an invalidation process which makes the above code pointless, yes?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the case where properties only affect Spark components,
>   wouldn't this be redundant since Spark components already defer their
>   property changes?

I don't believe this is a true statement.  Spark Components do not defer their property changes any differently than MX Components.

> But the setter for "label" in the Spark Button class is already using
>   an invalidation process which makes the above code pointless, yes? Or
>   am I missing something?

Yes, you are missing the fact that every spark component has it's own invalidation cycle.  this is no different from MX Components in which one MX Component contains another.

I'm not clear, but you appear to be looking at two identical things (MX Invalidation and Spark invalidation) and saying they are different.

Comment: Thanks, Flextras.  The intent of my question wasn't meant to compare MX to Spark.  I only mentioned Spark because it was in those components that I examined the component code.  What I meant to address was the idea of optimizing CPU cycles by using the Invalidation Cycle and how it didn't seem useful for simple operations.  In the example above, the buttonLabel setter was attempting to "protect" myBtn.label from being set too many times in a frame.  But the label setter for Button already has it's own checks for this, so why wrap it again (at least for this specific example)?

Comment: You aren't wrapping it up again; because you are you dealing w/ 2 separate components & two separate LifeCycles--even though one is a child of the other. Perhaps 15 properties will be changed on the main comp, which relates to 3 changes on the button child.  It usually makes sense to coordinate those changes to one spot.  If you could guarantee no property will change in conjunction w/ other properties, then feel free to ignore the invalidation process.  When building for reuse; you don't want to assume this.  When building for your own app it may be okay.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're getting at: commitProperties is effective when more than one property will be changed a time within a cycle (I guess I would add that it's also effective if changing a property triggers an extensive computation).  Could you submit a formal answer so I can credit the answer to you?

Comment: I did submit a formal answer; that is what we're commenting on.